# how to test multipart post with RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm trying to test a multipart/form post with RSPEC with the following code:

```
@req = { :post => @attr }
  lambda {
    post :create, :POSTDATA => @req, :format => :json
  }.should change(Post, :count).by(1)
```

but I get the following error:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "post":String
```

POSTDATA is the multipart form name.

what is the correct way for testing multipart requests ?

EDIT:

I figured out that building the request like I did in the above just builds a nested JSON request.   how do I build a multipost/form request ?

I want to build a multipart request that looks like that:

```
POST /api/posts.json HTTP/1.1
Accepts: application/json
X-API-KEY: 7d867d16a5e25337b6d7857965f812bee73b76ac
Content-Length: 288
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=syoYQUQsGwI2XqShQimFdv2QSe-_GYbjVx40T1kS
Host: 10.0.2.2:3000
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

--syoYQUQsGwI2XqShQimFdv2QSe-_GYbjVx40T1kS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="POSTDATA"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

{"tags":["dffdff"],"location_id":3,"post":{"content":"test #dffdff"}}
--syoYQUQsGwI2XqShQimFdv2QSe-_GYbjVx40T1kS--
```

Comment: take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260394/test-a-file-upload-using-rspec-rails

Comment: i don't seem to find a related answer there. i'm not trying to test uploading of a file

Comment: Vik, can you please point me to what I'm looking for on that link ?

Comment: Hey Gal,
I was assuming that you are trying to test to upload any files , as you are using 'multipart/form' request . And as I know we used this to upload the things . It was wrong assumed .

Comment: any ideas how to build such request with RSPEC ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you trying to create a new object (create method) while transferring just a hash to it .

Try :

```
 post :create, {:model_name => {hashed_parameter}, :format => :json }
```

And don't make it constant POSTDATA , simply use :post_data .

And also suggest to use the Factory Girl to create object and use into test .

Comment: I updated the question with an example of the multipart request that I'm trying to build