# File Upload Using Paperclip With Rspec Testing (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, paperclip, rspec-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [test a file upload using rspec - rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260394/test-a-file-upload-using-rspec-rails)

I don't know how to write test cases for file uploads. can you please help me

I have form with user_photo, name, email. i write test cases for name and email

like

```
 fill_in "user_name", :with => "xyz"
 fill_in "user_email", :with => "test@test.com"
```

but how can i write test cases for select photo ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have used paperclip then I can help you in this..

Write your test case like this

```
def do_upload_file
# write the request for the action as defined in your routes file
# get :upload_file, :id => :user_id (id of the user)
end

before do
 # set the session variables and other parameters here..
end

it "should upload the file correctly" do
  @user.should_receive(:update_attributes).and_return(true)
  do_upload_asset
  response.should redirect_to(whatever_path)
end
```

Works for me and can hopefully work for you too....

Comment: how can i upload a particular jpeg/png file for testing?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using:

```
obj.asset = fixture_file_upload('/dummy_file.png', 'image/png')
```

where you can define the fixture path in your spec helper as :

```
config.fixture_path = "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
```

[Official documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/TestProcess/fixture_file_upload)