# How to convert the curl request in rspec test file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How do I convert the following CURL POST request to rspec controller test file.

The controller#method I test is `remote_test#upload`

```
curl -X POST -F report=@readme.md  
-H "X-User-Email: poc.hsu" -H "X-User-Token: WKyi9yAtquCn" 
-H 'X-Test-Token: bpBJHA' 
http://localhost:3000/remote_test/upload
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that you must do something like:

```
post "path/to/route", {}, {'HTTP_ACCEPT' => "*/*", 'X-User-Token' => 'user_token_example', 'X-Test-Token' => 'bpBJHA'}
```

The second parameter is the optional parameters that you could pass to post or get methods.

Best regards!

Comment: but how about i need to upload some binary files ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the -F option. Look this related answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260394/test-a-file-upload-using-rspec-rails

Answer (score -3):

ruby has **system** method to execute os commands such as **ls**, *cd* etc. 
Of course including **curl**. (if the os can have the commnads)

```
system('curl http://www.yahoo.com')
# => return www.yahoo.com html ...
```