# Why is fixture_file_upload not available in RSpec (without ActiveRecord)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test a file upload using RSpec 3.7 in a Rails 5.2 app, and the simplest recommendation I've seen (several places, [including this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260394/test-a-file-upload-using-rspec-rails)) is to use `fixture_file_upload` - which looks great, except that it doesn't seem to be available in my app, and I don't know why.

The only thing I can think of is that our app is not using ActiveRecord, it's using MongoID.  But ActiveRecord shouldn't be required to use these methods... they're totally unrelated. Is there another new "ActiveSomething" library in Rails 5 that I'm missing? (this app was upgraded from a Rails 4 app...)

To explain my problem more concretely, I've tried putting:

```rb
let(:file) { fixture_file_upload('invalid_csv.csv') }
```

in one of my contexts, and it raises an exception:

```
undefined local variable or method 'fixture_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::...>
```

I tried defining `config.file_fixture_path` [as outlined here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/file-fixture), and that raises it's own exception:

```
undefined method `file_fixture_path=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration::...>
```

Does this work at all? Clearly I'm missing something...

Comment: How about change `config.fixture_path = "#{Rails.root}/xxx/xxx"` in RSpec.configure?

Comment: I tried that as well, and I got the same error "undefined method for `fixture_path=` for <RSpec::Core::Configuration...>"

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I ended up writing my own `fixture_file_upload` helper that was just `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join("spec/fixtures/#{path}"), mime, true)`. Seems like a ridiculous thing to do but it works in Rails6 and lets me get on with the upgrade so...

Comment: I don't think I figured this out, no.  I think I just used workarounds like that.  However, it appears it should be part of ActionDispatch::TestProcess::FixtureFile in Rails 6: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/TestProcess/FixtureFile/fixture_file_upload

Comment: I am having the same problem since I have upgraded from Rails 6.0 to Rails 6.1. By using the `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join("spec/fixtures/#{path}"), mime, true)` as mentioned above has worked around the problem to me.

Comment: If someone still having this problem currently can test the proposed answer below, and let me know, I'll mark it as correct! :)

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed this by including their module on the RSpec config block:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  #...
  config.include ActionDispatch::TestProcess::FixtureFile
  #...
end
```

Comment: Nice!  I can't test right now, but if someone else can confirm that it works for them as well, I'll mark this as correct :)

Comment: Didn't work for me, upgraded from 6.0 to 6.1

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```rb
Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join("spec/fixtures/doc.pdf"))
```